# How to allow access to Ceph/S3 objects between multiple users?

Tags: ceph

We have a Ceph filesystem we're accessing via Ceph/S3 interface. We have a bucket owner user `user-00` and multiple individual user accounts `user-01`, `user-02`, etc.

When `user-02` uploads a file we're seeing the following from `get-object-acl`:

```
{
    "Owner": {
        "DisplayName": "User 02",
        "ID": "user-02"
    },
    "Grants": [
        {
            "Grantee": {
                "DisplayName": "User 02",
                "ID": "user-02",
                "Type": "CanonicalUser"
            },
            "Permission": "FULL_CONTROL"
        }
    ]
}
```

When `user-01` attempts to copy that file they're getting the error:

```
An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the UploadPartCopy operation: Unknown
```

Our bucket policy aims to be full access for all authenticated users:

```
{
    "Policy": {
        "Version": "2012-10-17",
        "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AllowAllForAuthenticatedUsers",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "*"
            },
    "Action": "*",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket",
                "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
  }
}
```

`user-02` originally uploaded the file via normal means using `aws` cli, no per-object ACL was set. We need a solution that ensures that when an object is uploaded by one user other users have ability to access it (hopefully without a service that edits per-object ACLs as they go up).